# ASP.NET MVC app - how to send data in body of a POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying out my hand at ASP.NET.  For now, I'm just trying to prove to myself that I can get a json array.

I have the following code:

```
    [Route("widgets")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string createbulkwidgets([FromBody] string request)
    {
        return request;
    }
```

I'm using POSTMAN to send the following:

POST to http://localhost:5000/widgets

and I have defined a body - raw - json that includes this:

```
{
 "cars": [
    { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
  ]
}
```

**Problem**

When I try to run my code, the request string is always NULL.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

No compile / build errors though.

Comment: Hey @dot - Im a little confused what is going on here. So, I think FromBody just binds a parameter/property to the request body. In your api method listed above, if the request is not null when passed from the calling method, your return request will not be null. Can you set a break point right after on your open bracket of the api method, then hover your mouse over the request parmeter -  "public string createbulkwidgets([FromBody] string request)" ? If that is null, then the issue is in your calling method (most likely in your web controller). Is the json shown, the request or the response?

Comment: Yes it is null when I hover over the function/ method signature.  I’ll have to poke around to see what this base controller I’m inheriting from.  I am using an existing framework if you will.  Just not familiar enough with asp.net to know what I should be looking for.

Comment: Can you show the controller that's calling this api method? In it, you should build up the string request thats being passed to the method you've shown above. Hao Guo has a point on that you should restructure your flow a bit. I prefer to to create a view model, with the objects named exactly as they appear in the json (name, models), because it will make life easier when converting the json result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
public class CarsItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Models { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<CarsItem> Cars { get; set; }
}

[Route("widgets")]
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public Root CreateBulkWidgets([FromBody] Root request)
{
    return request;
}
```

You got null request string because ASP.NET will convert the JSON to a instance according to the JSON format, so you should define a model to receive it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: so I added  model to define it. But when i get the data... i can see that the list is still empty.